# Qt-PyQt5 is it possible to put interval between every letter when set a text to QLineEdit.setText()

Tags: python, qt, setinterval, pyqt5

My goal is, when I set a string `QLineEdit.setText(string)`, I want to see that string's letters appear letter by letter, like there is an interval between every letter.

I tried to use `pyautogui.typewrite(string,interval = 0.25)` but it didn't work. Also I tried a for loop on the string like;

```
tt = "Test"
for x in tt:
    QLineEdit.setText(x)
```

But it only wrote the last character which is t. I'm wondering is it possible to make this in PyQt5?

**Edit:** Is it at least possible in Qt? maybe I can convert it to PyQt?

Comment: This should be relatively easy with a timer. Cache the final text string and an integer representing the position in the string. Every time the timer fires, add another character.

Comment: @JonHarper could you show a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ pseudocode and comments (my Python is too rusty to be useful):

```
class DelayedLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    ...
public Q_SLOTS:
    void setTextDelayed(const QString &txt);
protected Q_SLOTS:
    void updateText();
private:
    QTimer textTimer;
    QString finalText;
    int currentTextPos;
}

void DelayedLineEdit::setTextDelayed(const QString &txt)
{
    finalText = txt;
    currentTextPos = 1;
    setText(finalText.left(currentTextPos);
    //connect the timer to updateText()
    //start your timer
}

void DelayedLineEdit::updateText()
{
    //increment currentTextPos and check if it's equal to the length of finalText
    //call setText with finalText.left(currentTextPos)
    //stop the timer if needed
}
```

It's pretty straightforward. When `setTextDelayed()` is called, you call `setText()` with the first character in the string and start a timer. Use the position variable to keep track of the number of characters you've appended, so set it to `1`.

When the timer fires, `updateText()` is invoked. Increment `currentTextPos` and call `setText()` with the new substring of `finalText`. When you reach the end of the string, stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with a timer, check it out. Don't mind the modules that I imported, too lazy to delete useless ones.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMessageBox,QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton,
                             QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QToolBar, QVBoxLayout,
                             QComboBox,QLabel,QLineEdit,QGridLayout,QMenuBar,QMenu,QStatusBar,
                             QTextEdit,QDialog,QFrame,QProgressBar,QHBoxLayout,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect,
                             QCheckBox
                             )
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QFont,QPixmap,QPalette,QWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt,QBasicTimer, QTimer,QPoint,QSize

import PyQt5.QtWidgets,PyQt5.QtCore


class Settings(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.set_widget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        #size
        self.setFixedSize(900,423)

        #line
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit.setGeometry(100,100,400,35)
        self.line_edit.setStyleSheet("color: white;"
                                     "background-color: rgb(0,0,0);"
                                     "border: 1px solid white;"
                                     "border-radius: 10px;"
                                     "font: bold 15pt 'Comic Sans MS'")

        self.timer26 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer26.timeout.connect(self.timergo)
        self.timer26.start(90)
        self.cnt = 0
        self.lst = ""

    def timergo(self):
        text = "I'm a text has interval between the letters"
        try:
            self.lst += text[self.cnt]
            self.line_edit.setText("".join(str(self.lst[::])))
            self.cnt+=1
        except:
            print ("index error")
            #or just pass

        self.show()



app1 = QApplication(sys.argv)
app1.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(0,0,0);border: 2px solid rgb(20,20,20)}")

ex1 = Settings()

sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
import time
tt = "Test"
for idx in range(len(tt)+1):
    text = tt[:idx]
    self.line_edit.setText(text)
    QApplication.processEvents()
    time.sleep(2)
```

change 2 to however many seconds you want the delay.

Edit* Solution updated with ekhumoro's edit

Comment: You can't use `time.sleep()` in PyQt, it has his own loop, so program will freeze. I tested it before. If using `time.sleep` the mainloop of windows are not working, so program freezing.

Comment: @GLHF. Actually, this will work. You just need to put `QApplication.processEvents()` before `time.sleep`. (And obviously it should be `self.line_edit.setText(text)`).

Comment: @ekhumoro well setting a timer is much elegant.

Comment: @GLHF. There are many different ways to solve problems like this. Using `processEvents` often provides the simplest solution. But I mainly wanted to point out that this answer is not completely wrong.